# Build custom condition dynamically setting parameters and operators

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sanitization

I'm having hard times trying to understand how to do the following thing:

I have a javascript that helps me dinamically building a filtering query, then encode it and send it as a param to rails.

The filter is built in this way: `myfilter = {"field": "birth_date", "comparison": "lt", "type": "date", "value": "2012-05-27"}}`

So I'm building, for my find method, a hash of conditions dynamically set.
The biggest problem is that I can be SQL-Injected even through field name of my query in this case. What do you suggest to build my find method?

I would like to do such a thing:

```
Client.where("? ? ?",myfilter['field'],myfield['comparison'].to_operator,myfield['value'])
```

But this is not valid. **How can I achieve this keeping my query sanitized?**

Comment: Actually all you are doing is describing the filter(s). Sanitise Column name against the table(s) meta data, operators against some list (or pass via say an enum), and then values as usual.

Comment: If you post it as an answer I can mark it, I actually did as you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are doing on the client end is describing the filter as in Name, Operator and Value. It's how you use them in the server end that could leave you open to an injection attack.

ColumnName can be checked against the columns in the query. operator against some sort of list of allowable values, or perhaps pass via an enum.

Values as usual.